# In react native android app is working in debug mode but after generate the APK file app is crashing

Tags: react-native

1.my application is working fine in debug mode.
2.when I generate the APK file app is installing and UI is working properly.
3.when I try to SIGNIN in my app my app is crashing.
4.I found some solutions and apply them but my problems is not solved

Comment: Can you add more details to this question?

Comment: Try to find some suitable logs from android studio and paste in your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of these problem
add these line in your AndroidManifest.xml file application section.

**android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).